# Apps Script query not copying over working row

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google form which once completed sends an email to management to authorise.  Once the form has been authorised, the spreadsheet updates with management response and the date replied.  I have also created a tracker sheet in case a form was approved but later rejected or vice versa.  The idea being the row gets copied over each time a change has been made.  The code I am using is:

```
    function doGet(e) {
  // Update Spreadsheet
  var answer = e.parameter.approval;
  var workingRow = e.parameter.r;
  var d = new Date()

  responses.getRange(workingRow, 12).setValue(answer);
  responses.getRange(workingRow, 13).setValue(d);
  var tracker = responses.getRange("A" + (workingRow) + ":Z" + (workingRow));
  copytoTracker(tracker)

  // Email
  var ctlEmail = e.parameter.reply;
  var sltName = e.parameter.sltName;

  // Send Approval Email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(ctlEmail, "Student Timetable Change Request", "Thank you for your timetable request.  Please note, " + sltName + " has responded to your request and it has been " + answer);

  var app = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(sltName + " thank you for your response.")

  //var emailSubject = getDefaultEmailBody();

  return app

}

function copytoTracker(tracker) {

  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tracker");

  var source_range = tracker;

  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();

  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A" + (last_row + 1) + ":Z" + (last_row + 1));
  source_range.copyTo(target_range);


}
```

Where am I going wrong?  The response and date goes in the correct cells, however, the correct row is not being copied over only the first row each time.

The first row has not yet been authorised/rejected is this what is causing the error?

Thanks

Fazila

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Fazila. Please confirm the following claims: 1) The issue is in the `copytoTracker(tracker)` function. 2) In that function you are trying to copy a row from one sheet into another one. 3) Your issue is that only the first row of `responses` is being copied instead of the one you want to (workingRow). // Please also consider sharing a minimal example of your Spreadsheet so we can better understand the context of your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Further to that, could you please describe what the `responses` variable holds? I do not see it declared anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Hi thank you for responding carlesgg97 I've managed to resolved the issue with some help of course!  The issue was the name of the copyTotracker function.  I have another form using the same code and for some reason even though the script is bound to the spreadsheet it seemed to be getting confused between the two.  Changing the name of the function to copyToTracker seems to have resolved the issue for now.  Thanks again for your time.